# SQL create table missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table and it gives me error. Really don't know why

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
  EmployeeId int(11) NOT NULL,
  LastName varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
  FirstName varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
  BirthDate date NOT NULL,
  notes varchar2(255),
  CONSTRAINT employee_pk PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId)
);
```

Comment: do you really need 2500 for the first name?

Comment: It was typo.I edited my post

Comment: What **RDBMS** is this for? Oracle? MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? Something else entirely? Please add a relevant tag to your question. Also: how are you **executing** this SQL? From a GUI tool? From a programming environment? Please add more relevant context!

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00907

Comment: Have you googled this error message ?

Comment: @Ann: Please add the error message and additional information about your system to your question by editing it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020

Comment: Don't tell us the error message, we like to guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't specify the length of an `int`.

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
  EmployeeId int NOT NULL,
  LastName varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
  FirstName varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
  BirthDate date NOT NULL,
  notes varchar2(255),
  CONSTRAINT employee_pk PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeId)
);
```